# Rotate Lines To True North or Vertical

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-sf

I have a dataset that contains polylines which run diagonal and I would like to rotate the lines to vertical or true north in order to show the x axis data correctly. I've looked at the Rodrigues Formula but it's way over my head and was wondering if their is a package in R that I could use. See the example below, which I would need to rotate.

```
library(sf)
library(ggplot2)

ex<-structure(list(OBJECTID = c(10526, 10913), geometry = structure(list(
    structure(c(-103.47406, -103.46268, 31.47367, 31.48499), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg")), structure(c(-103.46525, 
    -103.4788333, 31.4879722000001, 31.4748056), .Dim = c(2L, 
    2L), class = c("XY", "LINESTRING", "sfg"))), n_empty = 0L, crs = structure(list(
    epsg = 4267L, proj4string = "+proj=longlat +datum=NAD27 +no_defs"), class = "crs"), class = c("sfc_LINESTRING", 
"sfc"), precision = 0, bbox = structure(c(xmin = -103.4788333, 
ymin = 31.47367, xmax = -103.46268, ymax = 31.4879722000001), class = "bbox"))), row.names = c(NA, 
-2L), sf_column = "geometry", agr = structure(c(OBJECTID = NA_integer_), .Label = c("constant", 
"aggregate", "identity"), class = "factor"), class = c("sf", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

ggplot(ex)+geom_sf()
```

Included a diagram of what I'm after

[image: Rotation]
thanks!

Comment: I believe it would need to be around the point closest to origin. There will be issues with rotating around the mid point or any other point for that matter if the polylines are of significantly different lengths though.

Comment: Not a good definition of origin on my part. I just want to rotate the lines to vertical but keep the distances between the two lines the same.

Comment: I've updated to include a diagram of what I am after. Left plot is original bearing/direction. Either of the right two plots are what I'm trying to do. Maybe rotating on the midpoint of the group of lines?

Comment: yes, they will always be parallel or close to parallel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Under the assumption all the lines are parallel, and the point of rotation is the centroid of all the lines, a way to do this is

1. Find the centroid of the lines
2. Find the bearing between the lines and due-north
3. Rotate each coordinate around the centroid
4. Done.

```
library(sf)
library(sfheaders)
library(ggplot2)
library(geosphere)

## get the centre of the lines
centre <- sf::st_centroid( sf::st_union( ex ) )

## remove class so we just have coordinates as a vector
centre <- unclass( centre[[1]] )

## get each coordinate of the lines. These will each be rotated
coords <- sf::st_coordinates( ex )

## to know the angle of rotation, we need to know due-north from a given point
## under the assumption all lines are parallel, we just need the bearing between the 
## start of a line and the end
##
## you're using lon / lat values, so we can use geosphere package to get the bearing
bearing <- geosphere::bearing(
  p1 = coords[1, c("X","Y")]
  , p2 = coords[2, c("X","Y")]
  )


theta <- bearing * pi / 180 ## in radians

#' rotate
#' function to rotate x and y coordinates around a point
#' theta - angle of rotation
#' p - point(s) to rotate
#' centre - centre point
rotate <- function( theta, p, centre ) {
  new_x <- cos( theta ) * ( p[, 1] - centre[1] ) - sin( theta ) * ( p[, 2] - centre[2] ) + centre[1]
  new_y <- sin( theta ) * ( p[, 1] - centre[1] ) + cos( theta ) * ( p[, 2] - centre[2] ) + centre[2] 
  return( matrix( c( new_x, new_y ), ncol = 2 ) ) 
}

## calculate the rotated points
coords_new <- rotate( theta, coords, centre )

## we've kept order in tact, so we can cbind the L1 id back on
coords_new <- cbind( coords_new, coords[, "L1"])

## new sf object (using library(sfheaders) )
sf_new <- sfheaders::sf_linestring( obj = coords_new, linestring_id = 3)
sf::st_crs( sf_new ) <- sf::st_crs( ex )

## plot to verify
ggplot() + geom_sf( data = sf_new ) + 
  geom_sf( data = ex ) + 
  geom_sf( data = sf::st_centroid( sf::st_union( ex ) ) )
```

[image]